# Introduced MySQL DATETIME(3) field => .NET DataTable.Load() fails now

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, milliseconds

After introducing a DATETIME(3) field (datetime with scale 3 for fractions/milliseconds) in one of my MySQL tables, my .NET application fails now at the DataTable.Load(MySqlDataReader) call:

```
MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException
Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

   bei MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime.GetDateTime()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   bei System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
   bei System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   bei System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   bei System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   bei System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
   bei DimensionData.Apps.DatabaseInterface.ds_Main.ExecuteMySql(String p_Sql, DataGridView p_Output) in C:\1 - Data\dev\Database Interface\Database TestApp\ds_Main.cs:Zeile 1011.
```

---

The code snippet:

```
DataTable l_Table = new DataTable();
MySqlCommand l_SqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `testtable`", ConnectionIsAlreadyPrepared);
MySqlDataReader l_SqlReader = l_SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
l_Table.Load(l_SqlReader);              // <-- MySqlConversionException
```

---

Some of the properties of the reader's resultset's value for the affected field, via Visual Studio debugger:

```
Day = 14
Hour = 16
IsNull = false
IsValidDateTime = true
Microsecond = 123000
Millisecond = 123
Minute = 10
Month = 6
Second = 11
TimezoneOffset = 0
Value = {14.06.2016 16:10:11}
Year = 2016

Ticks = 636015174111230000
TimeOfDay = {16:10:11.1230000}

MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.MySqlDbType = DateTime
MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.MySqlTypeName = "DATETIME"
MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.SystemType = {Name = "DateTime" FullName = "System.DateTime"}
MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.Value = {14.06.2016 16:10:11}
```

---

The versions:

MySQL Connector/Net (mysql.data): 6.9.8.0

MySQL ServerVersion: 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

---

The table and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `idtesttable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `testvarchar` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `testdatetimenew` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtesttable`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `testtable` (`idtesttable`,`testvarchar`,`testdatetime`,`testdatetimenew`) VALUES (1,'test','2016-06-14 16:01:02','2016-06-14 16:10:11.123');
```

---

### Solution

I am so sorry, but this was my fault! I re-created the testtable and now everything is working fine!

I don't know the reason, but there has to have been some kind of corruption to the datatype of the `testdatetime` field as the proposed workaround of Rahul below wasn't working. After altering the datetime type of this field to datetime(0), everything works now without CAST!

I am sorry, that my description here indicated a szenario in which I created the table from scratch, which wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should in that case modify your query to convert that to `DATETIME` like

```
SELECT `idtesttable`,
`testvarchar`,
`testdatetime`,
CAST(`testdatetimenew` AS DATETIME) AS Newdt
FROM `testtable`;
```

Also, if this exception is happening then make sure your used connector supports the specific MySQL version you are using. I am sure, you need to upgrade or use a different connector version.

Comment: Thank you Rahul for your help, but when your statement didn't helped, I investigated my testtable and found out a weird corruption: the `testdatetime` column seems to have been datetime(3) under the hood, while pretending to be datetime only. I can only guess the reason for this (Workbench 6.0.8.11354 not fully compatible - cause it displays this type inconsistently as well, or historic schemata corruptions as I upgraded the mysql server from 5.5 to 5.6 while encountering the lack of milliseconds support of 5.5). I didn't re-created the table at the end, this was my fault, sorry!

Comment: @Nicolas, that's total weird. Well, do one thing ... since you have already upgraded server version to 5.6, as you already have pointed ... do drop and recreate the table (just rename the existing table to something, as a backup) and see if that helps. My assumption is that, somehow your upgrade has corrupted the table schema but can't say for sure. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. But I dropped the old table, instead of renaming it - so nothing left to experient with... well ... not that great loss to mankind ;-) nevertheless thank you for your help!